# App Store bug on certain iOS/Hardware and not others

Tags: iphone, debugging, app-store

I am about to submit an iPhone app to Apple for the first time. I was wondering: if they find a bug only in iOS 3.0 (for example) would they allow you to release only for iOS 4.0 (and above) even though you targeted 3.0 and above?

Likewise, if you have targeted the original iPhone device, but there is a bug found when your app is run on it, but not on any of the other devices, will they allow you to release for those?

Or is the answer to the above "NO. You have to debug, resubmit and wait yet another month".

Thanks!

Comment: It's not always another month.

Comment: Yeah. It's usually a couple days or so.

Comment: @BoltClock, @ceejayoz Meaning you can resubmit with different targets and goes through within a week, give or take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; if you set your deployment target to 3.0 and it doesn't work on 3.0 and above, then your app should and probably will be rejected. Your only option is to either thoroughly test on older OS versions, or raise your app's deployment target to a version which you're confident your app will work on.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the deployment target to any version you want as minimal requirement... so if your app requires 4.0 or 4.2 you can set this and it won't have to run on old devices.

On the other side your app has to run without crashes on actual 4.3 devices.. you can't submit an application that only runs on old devices.

If you change the deployment target you have to recompile and resubmit.

Comment: Right, but what I'm concerned about here is the process of submitting it to the App Store. I don't want to be going back and forth for months :)

Comment: I'm not sure how they are testing .. but problems with old versions are usually found by the automated tests shortly after submit. I'm not sure that a human tester will test the app with an old ios version at all.